# The best solution for background application logic?

Tags: html, angular, angular-components

I have 2 different types components. They both only use and contain an HTML5-canvas element, but need to show different types of data on a chart:

1. Component A (Only ever 1 of these)
2. Component B (0 to 4 of these)

Both components need the dateTime of the first data-entry from the two data-sets, but the dateTime of the last entry comes from their own respective data-sets.

*Component A* needs its first entry date from *Component B.*

Currently I do it like this:

Component B has the method that finds the date-limits from its own dataset. Using an Observer-pattern & Subjects, I broadcasts the returned dates through a service and into Component A.

The problem with this though, is that coupling suddenly becomes pretty tight. I can't initialize component A first, because it needs B to do its calculation first. Both components ideally should initialize and show/share their data simultaneously, and continue to do so. (E.g. If a user scrolls in one chart it should scroll all other components too, and so on.)

This is why I wanted an extra layer added on top of these components. A controller if you will.

**I can't figure out what's best though:**

---

- A shared service that can take external data as input?
- A container component? (Transclusion)
- Another component, *Component C*, that *A & B* are children of?
- As I'm still new to Angular 2, it's hard to tell which approach is best for future maintenance/development?

  ---

I'm being drawn towards creating another normal component as a parent, and have this component send and receive data to/from its children (A & B) as necessary.

I'm also uncertain as to what's "best practice" and if you can just use a component like an empty 'logic shell'. I've tried reading here and there, and I've found a lot, but I can't seem to get an exact answer to my question. It'll take time before I can comprehend all this knowledge and answer it myself, so I'm hoping someone could give me a helping nudge, thanks.

PS: I should add that my angular application will be a child-component in larger application, and will get its data from some other parent comp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put your logic into services?
You can also set up service hierarchies by injecting sub-services into a parent service.

If your logic is not UI / interaction related, you should put it into reusable services. If your logic is UI related, you could set up a parent component acting as a mediator between A and B (acting on their respective input/output parameters)

Whatever you do, it is a good idea to keep concerns separate.

- Both A and B should not need to care about other components needing their output. Angular has Input/Output parameters for that.
- Don't put some generic datetime calculation stuff into components. Make it reusable through services.
- Keep coupling loose by introducing interfaces and injections.

Update:

Services should only use injectable constructor parameters, so you should pass your input using methods (or setters, but that is less expressive).
To pass arbitrary JSON objects, you could utilize any parameters. However if your json follows a certain structure, you could define an interface.

```
public doStuff(input: any): any { }
```

or

```
interface IMyDataContract {
    dateField: string;
}

public doStuff(input: IMyDataContract): any { }
```

Comment: My logic is related to manipulating/searching a JSON dataset, in order to   to draw the data on HTML5-canvas elements. I should be able to use services, but I had trouble passing the JSON-data to the service as an input.

Thanks a lot for the answer, I'm going to try the service solution again.

Comment: Just define a method and parameters. Your services should only contain injectable constructor params

Comment: Aha, interesting. This seems promising. I'll try and see if I can make it work now, and I'll return :). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think I got a pretty nice idea about what you were saying, and it's definitely working a lot more smooth now. I put some logic into services and also created a parent-component that mediates input data to its children! Thanks for the help, greatly appreciated! :) PS: Sorry for the long wait time.